# Javapackager - include Java executable

Tags: java, java-10, javapackager

In the configuration of javafx-maven-plugin, I use the bundleArguments to include the jdk.shell into my package.

```
                <bundleArguments>
                    <add-modules>jdk.jshell</add-modules>
                    <icon.icns>src/main/resources/icns/icon.icns</icon.icns>
                </bundleArguments>
```

Which works fine, however I also need the Java executable to be placed in the Java.runtime/Contents/Home/bin folder. Anyone know if that is possible?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Got it....

```
                <bundleArguments>
                    <strip-native-commands>false</strip-native-commands>
                    <add-modules>jdk.jshell</add-modules>
                    <icon.icns>src/main/resources/icns/icon.icns</icon.icns>  
                </bundleArguments>
```